# OAuth 2(Pinterest) - Query Param in callback URL?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, callback, pinterest

My OAuth 2 callback URL is:

```
https://www.my-site.com?fixed=value
```

Where I have a query param that's fixed and does not change(and it unfortunately needs to be there for unrelated reasons). When Pinterest does the redirect call after user logs in, they add the `?`  again. So something like:

```
https://www.my-site.com?fixed=value?code=122343
```

Where my API is interpreting the value of the `fixed` param as `value?code=122343` and breaks down. Is there any around this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change callback url from `https://www.my-site.com?fixed=value` to `https://www.my-site.com/fixed/value` or you can try to add a custom parser to parse this url in your API.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the URL as I need to have the query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was having a query param option called 'state'.I put my constant data in it and after authorize, I got my constant data in 'state' query param again when I redirected to my app.